# Find Possible Original String From the Shuffled String

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

I have a problem. Here is the description.

> Distance between 2 strings is the sum of absolute difference between
>   the letters at same positions (e.g. difference("ab","cd") = 
>   abs('a'-'c')+abs('b'-'d') = 4). There is a string **orig**. Then, the
>   letters of **orig** is shuffled. Then, you can replace **only one**
>   letter from the string with its next or previous letter in alphabet or
>   do nothing (do not replace any letter). Let name the new string
>   **st**. Let **X** is distance between **st** and **orig**. Given **st**.
>
> My problem is, given **st**, I need to generete for every distance
>   **X** (where **X** = distance(orig, st), number of possible string **orig** from given string **st**.
>
> for more clear explanation: I need to generate the number of possible
>   string orig that can transformed to st that have distance(orig, st)
>   equal to **X** (where 0 ≤ x ≤ 250).
>
> constraint:
>
> - 'b' ≤ st<sub>i</sub> ≤ 'y'
> - 1 ≤ |st| ≤ 10
> - 0 ≤ X ≤ 250

I've tried to use dynamic programming with bitmasking, but it seems to slow for the problem (the complexity is arround O(2<sup>|st|</sup> * |st| * |X|)). Is there any better algorithm or data structure that suit to solve this problem? Any hint or opinion is very appreciated. Thank you :D

*let me know if there are unclear explanations :D